# Installing Ruby DevKit on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, devkit

I wish to install the Ruby DevKit on Windows. I'm using Ruby 2.0 on a 32 bit Windows.

Here is my procedure:

After downloading DevKit (for version 2.0), I place the files in C: then I run these two commands:

```
ruby dk.rb init
```

then:

```
dk.rb install ruby
```

The installation does not work and the console shows me this:

```
[INFO] Skipping Existing gem override for 'C :/ Ruby200'
[WARN] Skipping Existing DevKit helper library for 'C :/ Ruby200'
```

Do you have any idea of the problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are warnings that the DevKit is already setup for that Ruby.

If you want to "force" a reinstall of the DevKit vars then you need to do

```
ruby dk.rb install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you install Ruby on your windows machine?

I know that RubyInstaller installs a working version of DevKit for you

http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Comment: Hi, i've install Ruby 2.0.0-p481 (x64)

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer of @Azolo was a good hint, but didn't fully work. I needed to run it like this:

```
ruby dk.rb install --force
```